# Avoid multiple adding of content to Generics List

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

I create custom Nodes with one circle on the left and one on the right.
Everytime I connect two Nodes, I want to set `Boolean left` or `Boolean right` to true. When I connect two Nodes to one Node, I want to set both `Boolean right` and `left` to true. Currently I add mutliple entries without updating my Generics content.

My Code:

```
public static List<NodeList<Boolean,Boolean,String>> connectList = new ArrayList<NodeList<Boolean,Boolean,String>>();
private String linkedNodeID;
private Boolean right = false;
private Boolean left = false;
```

and the actual Code and here is where I make the actual mistake by adding always inside `leftTrue()`/`rightTrue()`:

```
public void leftTrue(){
    left = true;
    connectList.add(new NodeList<Boolean, Boolean, String>(left, right, linkedNodeID));
}
public void rightTrue(){
    right = true;
    connectList.add(new NodeList<Boolean, Boolean, String>(left, right, linkedNodeID));
}
```

What I got is:

```
right connected: false ,left connected: true ,ID: 81def74e-4cb6-428c-b7ca-a57279534814
right connected: true ,left connected: false ,ID: 46514df2-da7a-41e0-bdd7-43e6f15b4220
right connected: true ,left connected: true ,ID: 46514df2-da7a-41e0-bdd7-43e6f15b4220
right connected: true ,left connected: false ,ID: 2e85f320-43cf-4d83-8670-4e917f31cd25
```

and what I want is:

```
right connected: false ,left connected: true ,ID: 81def74e-4cb6-428c-b7ca-a57279534814
right connected: true ,left connected: true ,ID: 46514df2-da7a-41e0-bdd7-43e6f15b4220
right connected: true ,left connected: false ,ID: 2e85f320-43cf-4d83-8670-4e917f31cd25
```

Any ideas how to set the left/right connect without adding another entry to my list?

**EDIT:**

```
public void registerSource(String linkId, DragNode linkNode) {
    linkedNodeID = linkNode.getId();
    double nodeWidth1 = linkNode.getWidth()/2;
    if(DragNode.linkNodeOneX <= nodeWidth1){
        leftTrue();
    }else{
        rightTrue();
    }
}
public void registerTarget(String linkId, DragNode linkNode) {
    linkedNodeID = linkNode.getId();
    double nodeWidth2 = linkNode.getWidth()/2;
    if( DragNode.linkNodeTwoX < nodeWidth2){
        leftTrue();
        testprint();
    }else{
        rightTrue();
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

My problem is that when ever I call `leftTrue();` I create a new `connectList.add(new NodeList<Boolean, Boolean, String>(left, right, linkedNodeID));` entry, but if a Id is already in my List, it should update `left` or `right`. Any ideas? Like `connectList.get(i).getL();` and then if this equals another Id just set `right/false = true;`

**EDIT3:**

```
public void leftTrue(){ 
    left = true;
}

public void rightTrue(){
    right = true;
}
public void registerSource(String linkId, DragNode linkNode) {
    linkedNodeID = linkNode.getId();
    double nodeWidth1 = linkNode.getWidth()/2;
    if(DragNode.linkNodeOneX <= nodeWidth1){
        leftTrue();
    }else{
        rightTrue();
    }
    if(left || right){
      connectList.add(new NodeList<Boolean, Boolean, String>(left, right, linkedNodeID));
      left = false;
      right = false;
    }
}
public void registerTarget(String linkId, DragNode linkNode) {
    linkedNodeID = linkNode.getId();
    double nodeWidth2 = linkNode.getWidth()/2;
    if( DragNode.linkNodeTwoX < nodeWidth2){
        leftTrue();
    }else{
        rightTrue();
    }
    if(left || right){
          connectList.add(new NodeList<Boolean, Boolean, String>(left, right, linkedNodeID));
          left = false;
          right = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: No comment but downvote, thanks.

Comment: I see no code that used `leftTrue` or `rightTrue`. So it is hard to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: You need to either update the NodeList element contained in the list or remove the old object and add a new one. Am I right assuming that the order of NodeList elements in the List represents the order of the nodes and only neighbors can be connected?

Comment: @Lutz Horn I had this Code first, but my problem is more inside the `leftTrue`/`rightTrue` methods by multiple calling  `connectList.add();` @Sentry Right now every Node can be connected to any node, but I will fix this later

Comment: @Sentry I tried to add a new and remove the old but I don't know how.

Comment: So, to clarify, it is my understanding that you wan to add an item to this list if and only if the ID is unique. If the ID is already in the list though, you intend to update that item in the list (not add a new node with duplicate ID).

Comment: Yes exactly, if the item in the list, left and right should both be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store those left and right values and use them only once to create the new node after determining if their is left, right, or both.

```
if( DragNode.linkNodeTwoX < nodeWidth2){
    leftTrue();
}else{ 
    rightTrue(); 
}
if(left || right){
  connectList.add(new NodeList<Boolean, Boolean, String>(left, right, linkedNodeID));
  left = false;
  right = false;
}


public void leftTrue(){ 
  left = true; 
} 
public void rightTrue(){ 
  right = true; 
}
```

Comment: The size seems to be right, but all entries have the same left/right and id, I'll edit my post so you can see how my code looks like

Comment: I suspect that's to do with how you are actually calling registerSource() and registerTarget().

registerSource(String linkId, DragNode linkNode) and registerTarget(String linkId, DragNode linkNode) are probably both referencing the same linkNode without creating a new one. Is that correct?

Comment: Both refer different Nodes `public void bindEnds (DragNode source, DragNode target) {target.registerTarget (getId(), target);source.registerSource (getId(), source);}` When I used my Code before, I got different ID's but different entries from the same Node (none updated), now I got same ID's on the first two, and the third is another Node,  and in all entries left false, right true :/

Answer (score 0):

I made it to work by updating the leftTrue() and rightTrue() methods:

```
public void leftTrue(){ 
    left = true;
    //if the function is rightTrue() then set right = true;
    if(left && right){
        String testID = self.getId();
        for(int i = 0; i < connectList.size(); i++){
            String testID2 = connectList.get(i).getL();
            if(testID == testID2){
                left = true;
                right = true;
                connectList.get(i).setT(left);
                connectList.get(i).setI(right);
            }
        }
    }else{
        connectList.add(new NodeList<Boolean, Boolean, String>(left, right, linkedNodeID));
    }
}
```

Then my output only has three unique ID's with correct left/right:

```
right connected: false ,left connected: true ,ID: 6036bf0c-c514-454e-abbb-c9298800a585, listsize 3
right connected: true ,left connected: true ,ID: b78abcb8-a940-44e7-9429-11006b54dc79, listsize 3
right connected: true ,left connected: false ,ID: b3188490-2183-44ee-8fc6-5af0309766a8, listsize 3
```